# Best way to handle exceptions when the invoked method throws a lot of exception

Tags: java, exception, logging, rpc

I try to handle rpc exception like this

```
try {
    rpcService.invokeRemoteMethod(foo)

} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("invokeRemoteMethod failed, foo = {} ", foo);
    throw CustomException(e);
}
```

when the rpcService isn't available, for example timeout, this snippet of code will write a lot of stacktrace log to the file, which may consumes a lot of cup and memory.So I guess whether I can set some threshold, such as when the same exception accurs once a minute, I print the whole exception stack, 10 times a minute, I just print the exception message, 100 and more times, I log nothing.

Comment: do not stop to log errors! not logging errors is #1 in my top-ten programming most terrible mistakes. instead, stop invoking the remote method for some time, or fix your implementation, or kill the current thread, or whatever but please in the name of everything Good in the world, NEVER EVER ignore exceptions. They are red alert in a plane's cockpit or a nuclear plant, they are symptoms of a potentially lethal disease, not taking them into account is terrifying and will break the world and open a gate to the demons' realm. At most change the level of log....

Comment: Is the service usually up and stable?  Why do you think you need to worry about cpu/memory usage during logging?  Did a profiler indicate problems?

Comment: @spi I think system availability is much more import than the logging itself, that's why out team develop useful tool which can update the log level dynamically.

Comment: @AndrewS you can say that the service is not usually stable, we have a web project which depends on more than 100 rpc services. Sometime the rpc server is down which may throw a lot of exceptions

Comment: I really think the way to handle such case can be anything BUT stopping to logging errors... You are really trying to handle a problem with the worst possible solution. What need to be fixed here is WHY the rpc service is offline, not how to prevent anybody from knowing it.

Comment: @spi we have more that 100 rpc services, and can't guarantee they work all the time.And when they are not available we don't want to print a lot of unuseful logs(maybe just the exception message, not all the stackstrace).So I wonder if there is something like the JVM parameter  -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow to tune the log ouput

Comment: not I'm aware of, but any decent logging system can be configured in such way (eg. at least logback: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ex). Reducing the stacktrace or lowering the level for some loggers or exceptions is acceptable. Removing them not.

Comment: @spi I got your point

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, circuit breaker is appropriate pattern to control logging (and also to prevent DOS on service if latency is high). Circuit can be open if more that say 5 exception (can be configuration per service) continuously, so that application doesn't call and log error if remote service is down.

Depending on your project, you can either use open source circuit breakers or can write simple circuit breaker using AOP or wrapping RPC class with circuit breaker.

Very minimal example for understanding is

```
public abstract class CircuitBreaker
{
    private Circuit circuit;

    public CircuitBreaker(){
        circuit = new Circuit();
    }

    public void execute()
    {
        if(circuit.isOpen()) {
            throw CircuitOpenException();
        }

        invokeService();
    }

    protected void recordFailure(){
        circuit.recordFailure();
    }

    protected abstract <T extends Object> T invokeService();
}

public class RPCServiceExecutor extends CircuitBreaker
{
    protected Result invokeService() {
        try {
            Result result = rpcService.invokeRemoteMethod(foo);
            return new Result();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.recordFailure();
            logger.error("invokeRemoteMethod failed, foo = {} ", foo);
            throw CustomException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

when circuit isOpen don't log exception, when circuit is closed always log exception.

For more details and examples you can refer

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/CircuitBreaker.html

https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/

Hope this help. In case you need more detailed real example let me know.